# Unity C# new Vector3 problem

Tags: unity, c#

I get an error every time I try making a line with "new Vector3".

Example 1: `private Vector3 playerPos = new Vector3 (0, .5, 0);` **gives the error:**

> The best overload method match for 'UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float,
>   float, float)' has some invalid arguments

Example 2: `playerPos = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp (xPos, -8, 8), .5, 0f);` gives the same error.

I followed the exact line from [this video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/creating-a-breakout-game) except my y's are different (my doing) and this isn't the first time I had a new Vector3 problem either.

I'm also using 5.0.1 (DX11 if that helps also) and I have not found any solutions. I am quite new to this but Copy and Pasting isn't very hard. (If I do his y axis I get the same problem so it's not that.) I really need help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using 0.5f instead of just 0.5. I can't see why you should be having this problem with just `playerPos = new Vector3(0, .5, 0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify an `f` at the end of a decimal value in C#, it's assumed to be of type `double`. To preserve precision, `double` does not implicitly cast to `float`.

So because of the .5 you put in the y (rather than the -9.5f in the tutorial's code), your examples have the signatures:

```
new Vector3(int, double, int)
new Vector3(int, double, float)
```

...both of which can convert implicitly to `new Vector3(float, double, float)`, but that middle argument won't convert to the `float` type the constructor is expecting unless you explicitly cast it or append an `f`.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. But now every time I try and run it (F5) it wants to "Attach to Process" and opens a new window. I have no idea why and every time I "Attach" it opens a new Unity program and I believe it's from an older version. (Also it seems my C&P wasn't 100 :P)

Comment: @Magic, it's worth asking another question about that. If you're running it from Monodevelop/Visual Studio/other code IDE, try running it from Unity instead by clicking the play button. I'll confess I don't run with a debugger attached very often, so I don't know the correct flow when running the project from a code IDE.

Comment: Ah, alright. It doesn't seem to really do anything since it saves my codes once it's "complete" but thank you anyway.